How does autowiring by parameter name works in Spring?
I have the following working example where beans are autowired by parameter name. Note that it is working and no qualifiers used.
How this can be done? I can't reproduce it in my project.
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    public MyComponent(
        // other parameters...
        Counter myCounterOk,
        Counter myCounterFail,
        // remaining parameters...
    ) {
        // Constructor body
    }
}

public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Counter myCounterOk() {
        return new Counter(); // Assuming Counter instantiation is correct
    }

    @Bean
    public Counter myCounterFail() {
        return new Counter(); // Assuming Counter instantiation is correct
    }
    
}


You might need to add the -parameters argument to the compiler, which will make the compiler preserve parameter names in the compiled byte code.

How it can be set in Gradle? I don't see something like this

This is explained in the spring documentation (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention).

@M.Deinum so you mean it can be because of elder Spring?

No not compiling with the parameter names in the code.
